# remove tasks from ThreadPoolTaskScheduler pool Spring

Tags: java, spring

I am using ThreadPoolTaskScheduler and Scheduler to create tasks, but when I set a new task I want to remove a certain one or all of them how can I do this?

```
    @Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler createThreadPoolTaskScheduler() {
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(10);
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix(threadPrefix);
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize();
    return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
}
```

Adding the tasks:

```
private final Scheduler scheduler;
private ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler;
public void addTask(){
    FixedRateTask update = new FixedRateTask(this::executeOnRateMethod
            , initialDelay, waitTime);

    taskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(threadPoolTaskScheduler);
    scheduler.setTask(taskRegistrar.scheduleFixedRateTask(update));
}
```

It seems that calling:

```
taskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(threadPoolTaskScheduler);
taskRegistrar.scheduleFixedRateTask(update);
```

Adds threads to the pool everytime, Also canceling the scheduler is not working:

```
scheduler.getTask().cancel();
```

Comment: Please edit your question's title, because it has nothing to do with removing a scheduled task from the pool

Comment: @GeorgiPeev "remove tasks from ThreadPoolTaskScheduler pool Spring" it literally says remove task from pool

Answer (score 1):

When you scheduled a future `ScheduledFuture<?>` will be returned.The `ScheduledFuture<?>` has `scheduledFuture.cancel(false)`, it will cancel the scheduled task, which you have placed in the executor.

Comment: It was a while ago and I think I had some kind of a workaround, but my last line of the question says that canceling the task doesn't work. I will try again tho and write back.

Answer (score 0):

I was a little late with the answer, but maybe it will be useful to someone.

You need to add this line of code to the createThreadPoolTaskScheduler() method:

```java
threadPoolTaskScheduler.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(true);
```